# avoid fullscreen alert dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have made an `AlertDialog` with a custom view which is defined in xml. the problem is that the `AlertDialog` is shown in fullscreen however I do not want such behavior and I have set the dimensions of my view in xml. how to avoid fullscreen `AlertDialog`?

```
            View view=LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.not_connected,null);
        new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext).setView(view).show();
```

and the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/wifi_icon"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_wifi"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/wifi_message"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/wifi_icon"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/wifi_ok"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="14sp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/wifi_cancel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/wifi_ok"
    android:textSize="14sp"/>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating your problem.

Comment: @CommonsWare I edited my post. thanx

Comment: Rather than `LayoutInflater.from(mContext)`, try `getLayoutInflater()`, called on your `Activity`.

Comment: @CommonsWare `getLayoutInflater()` didn't work, too :(

Comment: Hmmm... OK, instead of inflating the layout yourself, try `setView(R.layout.not_connected)`. My database samples, like [this one](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Database/ConstantsROWID), use an `AlertDialog` with a custom view, and they do not fill the screen. I am having no problem with inflating the layout myself. Make sure that `mContext` is an activity,

Comment: @CommonsWare its strange! still doesn't work.

Comment: Final possibility: don't use a `RelativeLayout` as the root element. `RelativeLayout` acts strange when it does not know its parent container at the point in time when you inflate it. IIRC, my layout uses `LinearLayout`.

Comment: @CommonsWare after usining LinearLayout as the root element, now the height of the alert dialog doesn't fill the screen, but the width is out of control and actually fills the screen with some margins(I can not set its width)

Comment: Then poke around with my sample app that I linked to and see what else that I am doing different in mine than what you have in yours.